# Why karma isn't executing any tests?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jhipster

I've created a [JHipster](http://jhipster.github.io/) project and created a javascript spec, however when I run **karma start** I'm getting this output:

```
~/projetos/consami/src/test/javascript$ karma start
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux)]: Connected on socket -yuANSJ71nx8EeeomeZW with id 73836995
```

This is the configuration provided by JHipster:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: '../../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'main/webapp/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-partial/angular-translate-loader-partial.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-cache-buster/angular-cache-buster.js',
        'main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'main/webapp/scripts/app/app.js',
        'main/webapp/scripts/app/**/*.js',
        'main/webapp/scripts/components/**/*.js',
        'test/javascript/**/!(karma.conf).js'
    ],

    exclude: [],
    port: 9876,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
});
};
```

I'm really new with karma, but it should show the execution of the specs, not?

**NEW INFORMATION**

I don't know if it is correct, but when I opened karma in Chrome, the only lines importing javascript was:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="karma.js"></script>
```

I could be wrong but, it shouldn't load all files in files array?

Comment: Any other message logged out other than those you pasted?

Comment: nothing. If I open the browser I see a green row with debug button. When I click in debug  button, I get a blank page.

Comment: the _documented_ way to run the JS tests in JHipster is "grunt test". I have no idea what "karma start" does.

Comment: First of all change your logLevel to config.LOG_DEBUG and provide more console output for your issue

Comment: can you run karma start the name of the karma config file.js?

Comment: @JulienDubois where is it documented? I didn't found it in http://jhipster.github.io

Comment: @brevleq this is the usual task name for running grunt tests with Yeoman generator, but you are correct it is not really documented (just do a "grunt --help" but that's not enough). So I added a ticket for this: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1292

Comment: @JulienDubois I feel lost with the output of "grunt test", can't identify where are the errors in my code, this is the reason I need see the tests in Chrome. This way I believe I can identify where are the errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnally I've found a solution:

Installed [karma-jasmine-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-html-reporter) and executed:

```
karma start src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js --reporters html
```

Now I can see the results of the tests clicking in debug button in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Is `karma start --browsers Chrome --single-run` what you're looking for?